# closing mutual fund accounts from India

Tags: india, mutual-funds

I have been working outside of India for few years now and am interested to know if there is a way straight forward way to close / liquidate all mutual funds held in [CAMS](https://blog.bankbazaar.com/what-is-cams-and-what-does-it-do/) which is the registrater for Mutual Funds in India.

I intent to close / liquidate all my Mutual Fund holdings to an NRO account that I hold in my name

Can this be done at a single place or do I have chase each and every Mutual Fund Investment and do this separately ?

Answer (score 0):

Use myCAMS website or mobile app to redeem all your active mutual funds.
https://mycams.camsonline.com/